# How can I prevent the App Store from doing automatic update checks or notifications?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, notifications

I don't like the App Store app automatically checking for app updates, or showing me notifications when there are updates for my installed apps.  I prefer to take care of updates when **I'm ready** to update.

How can I prevent the App Store from automatically checking from updates, or from giving me the the little red notification when updates are available?

I've got an iPhone 4 running iOS 5.0.1.

Comment: This only pops up if you visit the app store. So only go to the app store when you are ready to update apps.

Comment: @GraemeHutchison - This does happen.  It seems to have changed with the 5.0.1 update.  Without me opening the App Store app, the notification badges appear.

Comment: There is no way. That functionality is not manageable by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, it seems there is no way to do that.

I checked the AppStore panel in the preference app, and the notification panel. No trace of an option to do that.

Sorry!